# How do I turn on gnome-sushi syntax highlighting?

Tags: 16.04, settings, previews, syntax-highlighting, gnome-sushi

I have seen several screenshots with syntax highlighting, but mine doesn't work. I couldn't find any related settings in the dconf Editor. How can I enable it?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, sushi installed with

```
apt-get install gnome-sushi
```

Comment: Just a random thing, but have you restarted lightdm (or just the whole computer)?

Comment: Doesn't work won't help us help you. What type of document/code are you expecting to see syntax highlighting in?

Comment: I have tried with python, json, sh, markdown and xml files. All of these files are syntax highlited in gedit. It would be nice if I could use my gedit theme and a fixed-width font with gnome-sushi. There are line numbers when I preview a source code-like file, but not when viewing a simple txt.
I have restarted my computer several times since installation.